# Prove that $|a^2-b^2| < 2|a| + 1$ given that $|a-b|<1$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $|a^2-b^2| < 2|a| + 1$ given that $|a-b|<1$

I understand that a variant of the triangle inequality is used in the solution: $|b| - |a| \le |a-b|$

I'm confused as to how it's derived, can anybody help me understand

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|a^2-b^2|=|a-b||a+b|<1.|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|<|a|+|a|+1=2|a|+1$$ where we used $|b|\leq |a|+|a-b|<|a|+1$. The last one follows from triangle inequality again:
Substitute in $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$ $x=b-a$ and $y=a$ to get $|b-a+a|\leq |b-a|+|a|$

Answer (score 0):

$$2|a|+1>|a^2-b^2|\ge|b^2|-|a^2|$$

$$\iff(|a|+1)^2\ge|b^2|\iff |a|+1\ge |b|$$

$$1\ge |b|-|a|\ge|b-a|$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$|a^2-b^2|=|a-b|\cdot|a+b|<|a+b|\le |a|+|b|\tag1$$
moreover,

$$|b|-|a|\le|a-b|<1\implies |b|<|a|+1\tag2$$
We deduce the desired result from $(1)$ and $(2)$.